# How do I move a sprite up and down in cocos2d with touch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to move my sprite up and down. Here is my code. I do not know the problem. It might be that the content size is messed up. The sprite just keeps disappearing.

```
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Player.png" 
                                           rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)];
    player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player z:1];
```

```
    (void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
    {
        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self 
                                                 priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    }

    -(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        return YES;
    }

    -(void)setPlayerPosition:(CGPoint)position {
        player.position = position;
    }

    -(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];       
        touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
        touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

        CGPoint playerPos = player.position;
        CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation, playerPos);
        if (abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y)) {
            if (diff.x > 0) {
                playerPos.x += contentSize_.width;
            } else {
                playerPos.x -= contentSize_.width; 
            }    
        } else {
            if (diff.y > 0) {
                playerPos.y += contentSize_.height;
            } else {
                playerPos.y -= contentSize_.height;
            }
        }

        if (playerPos.x <= (contentSize_.width *contentSize_.width) &&
            playerPos.y <= (contentSize_.height * contentSize_.height) &&
            playerPos.y >= 0 &&
            playerPos.x >= 0 ) 
        {
            [self setPlayerPosition:playerPos];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You won't get an answer that way.  You haven't even asked a question.
Go through some tutorials on cocos2d, then write some code that applies to your specific situation.  If you still have trouble, edit this message to include the code you've written.

See http://whathaveyoutried.com/ for more information about how to ask questions here.

Comment: Oh I have some code that I can share give me a sec.

Comment: Great!  I would also remove all the tags besides "cocos2d-iphone"   This isn't a question about iphone, objective-c, etc.